# Explanation more on org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.leaserenewer

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, apache-kafka-connect

The message from kafka topic is not written to hdfs.

**Reason :**

```
DEBUG LeaseRenewer:pratim_ghosh@localhost:9000, clients=[DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1103459197_28], created at java.lang.Throwable: TRACE
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.<init>(LeaseRenewer.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.<init>(LeaseRenewer.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$Factory.get(LeaseRenewer.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$Factory.access$100(LeaseRenewer.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.getInstance(LeaseRenewer.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLeaseRenewer(DFSClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.beginFileLease(DFSClient.java:811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:775)
    at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroRecordWriterProvider.getRecordWriter(AvroRecordWriterProvider.java:55)
```

Could anybody please explain.